# Avro "Invalid sync!" exception in nextRawBlock()

Tags: networking, streaming, avro

I am streaming a Avro encoded file over the network from a S3 compliant object store and trying to read it and put it in some data-structure.

**Issue:** The issue I am facing sometimes ( one or two times in one / two days in test node when running continuously) is that half way through the file it hits this exception `Invalid sync!`  in the `nextRawBlock()` method in `DataFileStream` class.

I would like to detect the root-cause of this and fix. I have been trying to
reproduce this in a test app but unable to do so successfully. I am looking for ideas on

- what might potentially cause this ?
- any better ways of reproducing this.

**More details**

a) The Avro file is not downloaded to disk , I get a handle to the file stream using S3ObjectInputStream and feed it to DataFileStream constructor
and then read from the stream directly.

b) The app tries to read records from the Avro encoded file in batches
 of 500 records at a time.

c) The file contains a header section containing a Long count and a KV Map of String to Integer. After that it contains a array of records where each record contains a String and a long array. The schema uses Avro's union construct for enabling this.

d) Number of records in the file on average is around 5M

e) This entire download happens in separate thread and not in any user request.

f) The file is uploaded to the store by a separate process.

Other observation:
a) Upon failure the app closes the stream and tries to again download and read the stream. What I observe is this takes the node to a high oldgen state slowing down user requests.